# Batch script to get file size

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a batch script to get the filesize and dump it to a .csv file. But the script is not posting any data for the file which is larger than 2GB. I am stuck at set targetDBSize function. Can someone please help me on this?

Below is the script:

```
set targetDBSize=

for %%G in ("\\opsprddb01\c$\Progra~1\Micros~1\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\%targetSite%.mdf") 

do set /A targetDBSize=%%~zG/1024/1024
```

Thanks,

Kalyan

Answer (score 0):

You have an arithmetic overflow. Try to execute this:

```
SET /A targetDBSize = 2147483647+1
```

Arithmetic is done over 32-bit signed integers, So the maximum filesize you can display safely is 2^31-1 = 2147483647

**SOLUTION:**

Use it in combination with Powershell

```
for /f %%N in ('powershell %~z2/1024/1024/1024') do set len=%%N
```

It works but it isn't very fast. It's easier to write your own script in a language where you can use floating points like VBScript of JavaScript.

Comment: Or, well, put the iteration and sum inside PowerShell as well ... e.g. `powershell "(ls '\\opsprddb01\c$\Progra~1\Micros~1\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\%targetSite%.mdf'|measure -sum).Sum/1gb"`. That way you don't have to start PowerShell once for each file needlessly.

Comment: @svekke

I tried the below: 

set targetDBSize= for %%G in ("\opsprddb01\c$\Progra~1\Micros~1\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\M‌​SSQL\DATA\%targetSit‌​e%.mdf") do set /A DBSize=%%~zG

for /f %%N in ('powershell %~z2/1024/1024/1024') do set targetDBSize=%%N

Still stuck.

-Kalyan

Comment: @VenkataKalyan put code inside backticks `\`like this\`` to make it readable